# question about wave equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Dalambert's formula for the  following BVP 
$$\hspace{35mm}u_{tt}=C^2u_{xx} ~~-\infty <x<\infty, t>0$$
$$u(x,0)=\phi(x)$$
$$u_t(x,o)=\gamma(x)$$

is that $$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}[\phi(x+ct)+\phi(x-ct)]+\frac{1}{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\gamma(x)$$

Know my question is that what is the behaviuor of the wave equation when $\phi(x)=0$,

Thanks.

Comment: What do you meean by *behaviour*? Exactly the same formula applies.

Comment: I probably write obvious thing, but it's
$$
u(x,t) = \frac 1{2c}\int_{x-ct}^{x+ct} \gamma(\tau)d\tau
$$

Comment: when $\gamma(x)=0$ then the wave has two part, one of them go to the right by speed $c$ and by half height, and another, go the left  by speed $c$ and by half height, now I want to know what happen when $\phi(x)=0$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As an example, suppose we want to solve the wave equation $u_{t t}=u_{x x}$ subject to $u(x,0)=0$ and $u_t(x,0)=2x \left/\left(1+x^4\right)\right.$. We can interpret this as follows. We impart an initial velocity to a very long string at rest. The precise initial velocity is given by $g(x)=2x\left/\left(1+x^4\right)\right.$. We might do this by striking the string in two locations with equal, but opposite vertical forces. Here is the graph of this function:

[image]

We can use d'Alembert's formula to find the solution analytically.

$$u(x,t) = \frac{1}{2}\int_{x-t}^{x+t} \frac{2s}{1+\left(s^2\right)^2} \, ds=\frac{1}{2}\arctan \left(s^2\right)|_{x-t}^{x+t}  = \frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan
\left((x+t)^2\right)-\arctan \left((x-t)^2\right)\right)$$

Here's the graph of $\arctan \left(x^2\right)$.

[image]

The solution is the superposition of two waves half this size; one is shifted to the left and the other is shifted to the right and reflected. At time $t=0$, the two waves cancel each other out and we get zero - the initial condition. A short time later, a downward hump appears to the left and an upward hump appears to the right. These two waves travel in their respective direction as time progresses. Here's an animation of this process.

[image]

I generated the animation with the following Mathematica code.

```
g[x_] := 2 x/(1 + x^4); 
u[x_, t_] = 1/2 Integrate[g[s], {s, x - t, x + t},
  Assumptions -> {Element[x, Reals], t > 0}];
Animate[Plot[u[x, t], {x, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {{-5, 5}, {-1, 1}},
  AspectRatio -> 1/3], {t, 0, 4}]
```

Comment: Thanks, it was so interseting.

Comment: @Hakhak Glad to hear you find it interesting!  In that case, you might consider giving it an upvote, or even an accept.  I notice that you've asked 14 questions without a single upvote or accept!

Comment: @Hakhak Thanks!!

Comment: @MarkMcClure One upvote from my side ...:). Could you tell me how you make this animation?

Comment: @srijan Thanks!  I generated the animation with Mathematica and have added the code.  If you happen to have access to Mathematica, I lifted this demo out of the "long waves" notebook here: https://sites.google.com/a/unca.edu/mark-mcclure/home/classes/spring-2013/pde

Comment: @MarkMcClure Thank you very much. I use mathematica . It is very nice. :)